# Can moderators see deleted comments?

Tags: discussion

Rather a simple question of curiosity: moderators can see deleted posts (both questions and answers), but can they see deleted comments too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes mods can. There is a feature where deleted comments can be exposed, but it has to be triggered to see the deleted items. (Tested with your question above).

Answer (score 8):

[image: Mod view of deleted comments]
[image: On mouseover]
[image]

Comment: I'm both impressed, and in awe of the effort you took to do this. -claps-